# wxHaskell not find module `Distribution.Compat.Exception'

Tags: cabal, cabal-install, wxhaskell

I am trying install wxhaskell on ubuntu
(and I have already installed wxwidget and it works well in codeblock)

I run `cabal install wxc` in terminal

and here is output

```
/tmp/wxc-0.92.1.1-2711/wxc-0.92.1.1/Setup.hs:25:8:
    Could not find module Distribution.Compat.Exception
    It is a member of the hidden package Cabal-1.22.5.0.
    it is a hidden module in the package Cabal-1.16.0
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Failed to install wxc-0.92.1.1
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
wxc-0.92.1.1 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

actually, I can find `Distribution.Compat.Exception` 
and I tried  `sudo ghc-pkg expose Cabal-1.16.0`
   `sudo ghc-pkg expose Cabal-1.22.5.0` but nothing changed

someone help me out, great thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ubuntu I think I have a solution. If you install GHC in ubuntu via "apt-get install ghc", all ghc packages are installed in /usr/lib/ghc/xyz. If you have installed ghc manually, not with a package manager, I don't know a solution.

Try this:

```
sudo cabal install cabal-install --global
```

Then do all the wxHaskell specific cabal installs the same way. So:

```
sudo cabal install wxdirect --global
sudo cabal install wxc --global
...
```

If this doesn't work, try this:

```
rm -rf ~/.ghc
```

Comment: please upvote the answer, quite a few people google this error and need a solution.

Comment: sorry i didn't check my message these days, your solution really works, thanks for your great help!  but... but another problem appears, so i finally gave up. now I have installed wxHaskell on Mac OS,